# android create zip file with txt files

Tags: android, zip

I want to create a zip file with txt files. Each txt file will be a string. Here is my code

```
        File f = new File("test.zip");
        f.mkdirs(); 
        try {
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("testfolder/mytext.txt"));

            byte[] data = stringInTXT.toString().getBytes();
            out.write(data, 0, data.length);
            out.closeEntry();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
```

I get a FileNotFoundException on

```
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
```

Is this the proper way to create a zip file with txt files? If so, how would I fix this exception?

Comment: please make sure that  the file exists!! by means check for a directory/file existence in a if block and than proceed in such a way that if directory/file does not exists than make a new one, always use a full path for path like resources!!

Answer (score 0):

You must type the entire path, including the drive letter and filename extension ,
at new File("test.zip");

Comment: Is there a default directory for android? I just need the zip file to be temporarily created before uploading it to a server.

Comment: There’re two ways.sdcard path,/data/data/your package name/your  temporary files..